# React-Router v6 and Material-UI Tab causing problems for the links in my homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a homepage where I need the links for the different pages.

```
<li>
          The tabs are located here - <Link to="/demo">Demo</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/page1">Page1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/page2">Pge2</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/page3">Pge3</Link>
        </li>
```

Under the `Demo` page are the tabs as well. I manage to keep the page on the current tab even though it was refreshed. However, my problem now is that on my homepage, if I'll click on the link for the `Pge2` or for the other pages, it shows nothing. It does not load the `Page 2`. I wanted to show just the page when I click on it, without the tabs.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictabs-demo-useparamas-7ockf0?file=/Homepage.js:342-402

**Routes**

```
    <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    <Route path="demo" element={<Demo />}>
      <Route path=":page1" element={<Page1 />} />
      <Route path=":page2" element={<Page2 />} />
      <Route path=":page3" element={<Page3 />} />
    </Route>
    {/* <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
    <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} /> */}
  </Routes>
```

**Demo.js**

```
export default function BasicTabs() {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let path = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(path);
    if (path === "/demo/page1" && value !== 0) setValue(0);
    else if (path === "/demo/page2" && value !== 1) setValue(1);
    else if (path === "/demo/page3" && value !== 2) setValue(2);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Homepage</Link>
      </li>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <h1>Some text here</h1>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Item One"
            {...a11yProps(0)}
            to="/demo/page1"
            component={Link}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Item Two"
            {...a11yProps(1)}
            to="/demo/page2"
            component={Link}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Item Three"
            {...a11yProps(2)}
            to="/demo/page3"
            component={Link}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      {value === 0 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
          <Page1 />
        </TabPanel>
      )}

      {value === 1 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
          <Page2 />
        </TabPanel>
      )}
      {value === 2 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
          <Page3 />
        </TabPanel>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd updated your sandbox. The problem is in the route definition. I will rewrite here (this will produce routes like `example.com/demo` `example.com/page1` as you are using in your tabs):

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/">
       <Route index element={<Homepage />}/>
       <Route path="demo" element={<Demo />}/>
       <Route path=":page1" element={<Page1 />} />
       <Route path=":page2" element={<Page2 />} />
       <Route path=":page3" element={<Page3 />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Explanation: you defined your route as descendants of 'demo', so your path will look like: `example.com/demo/page1` while you wanted to be `example.com/page1`

If you are intending to use your routes as `example.com/demo/page1` then leave your path definition unmodified and instead update your App component and add to your tabs: `demo/page1` and so on

```js
<Link to="/demo/page1">Page1</Link>
```

Comment: I think you should add " / " instead of " : " in value of path

Comment: however, This solution will break the routes inside demo page

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to navigate from your `Homepage` component to other `Pages` then you need to add new routes to your `app.js`

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    <Route path="demo" element={<Demo />}>
      <Route path=":page1" element={<Page1 />} />
      <Route path=":page2" element={<Page2 />} />
      <Route path=":page3" element={<Page3 />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
    <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
  </Routes>
```

This won't break the routes inside `Demo` page and if you want different content to be displayed then you can create new `components` and provide them as a value for `element` prop

Comment: I don't think that's the intention

Comment: @Meet Bhalodiya this does work but are there any workarounds instead of defining each of those pages again?

Comment: If you want to achieve the same thing then, I don't think so there are any other ways to do this, as per my knowledge